# In Swift, how do you convert a CGSize into its string representation?

Tags: swift

I know in Objective-C you use `NSStringFromCGSize(size)` to convert a `CGSize` into its string representation, but what's its equivalent in Swift?

Comment: LMGTFY -> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromCGSize

Comment: OMG 404 ROFLMAO

Comment: Why can't it redirect to: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1624514-nsstringfromcgsize?language=objc or https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoder/1624514-string ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply call NSStringFromCGSize(size)

```
var size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
var str = NSStringFromCGSize(size)
```

it's this quite simple in swift ;)
The method in swift returns a String

If you use the () syntax to convert, as mentioned below, it will be a different result to the call of the convert method.

```
var size = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
var str = NSStringFromCGSize(size) // "{10, 10}"
var str2 = "size: \(size)" //"size: (10.0, 10.0)"
```

I tested it out in a playground. And when i look at result i would use the convert method.

Answer (score 8):

These days, you use this:

```
let size: CGSize
let str = NSCoder.string(for: size)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscoder/1624514-string

Answer (score 0):

They are the same:

```
import UIKit

var _size = CGSize.zeroSize
println("Size: \(NSStringFromCGSize(_size))") // "Size: {0, 0}"
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromCGSize